# Angular FormBuilder US Phone Number Regex (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am trying to write an Angular Regex validator,

which matches this and only this pattern for phone, spaces exact

```
(444) 333-2222
```

How can this be done?

```
this.productForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'homephoneNumber': [null, [PhoneUSValidator]],
```

**Working on this Code:**
Trying to add the space, after the first parenthesis, not sure if correct

```
export const PhoneUSValidator = Validators.pattern(/^(\d{3}\)\d{3}\-\d{4}$/);
```

Comment: So, add the space, and escape the first `(`, `/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/`

Comment: hi @WiktorStribiżew feel free to write in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

- Add a literal space (or `\s` to allow any whitespace) *exactly* at the location where you expect it to be in the string
- Escape the `(` char after `^` because you need to match a literal open parenthesis.
- Do not escape `-` that is outside of a character class, i.e. not inside `[...]`.

You may use

```
/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VIDgWD/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- - a space
- `\d{3}-\d{4}` - three digits, hyphen, four digits
- `$` - end of string.